# Though, Although and However

Tags: word-usage

What is difference between uses of *although*, *though* and *however*?

e.g.:

> However/Although  Khan Abdul gaffer Khan was a devout Muslim who had declared his allegiance to Pakistan despite initial opposition to the partition.

Answer (score 2):

"Although" and "though" are used to introduce *dependent* clauses, while "however" can also introduce *independent* clauses, which can function as whole sentences. This is a sentence by itself, so it must not be a dependent clause.

Put another way, there has to be another part of the same sentence that says "although X, ***Y***" or "***Y*** although X". This sentence is missing the "Y". But "however" does not grammatically need that; instead, it can rely on being put near some other sentence or thought that it stands in contrast to. For example, a preceding paragraph might have mentioned that some would have thought that Khan Abdul gaffer Khan's initial opposition to the partition would remain. The "however" then introduces a contrasting thought, an exception.

Assuming that the author intended to use "however" to create a sentence from an independent clause like this, there should ideally be a comma after "however".

There are two exceptions to all this. The first is that "though" (but *not* "although") can be put at the end of a sentence to act like "however" and introduce an independent clause after the fact. So this works, although it sounds awkward:

> Khan Abdul gaffer Khan was a devout Muslim who had declared his allegiance to Pakistan despite initial opposition to the partition**, though**.

The second is that the sentence can be rearranged fairly easily to make it simpler and rely on a dependent clause… which would, yes, be introduced with "although" or "though". For example:

> Although Khan Abdul gaffer Khan was a devout Muslim**, he** had declared his allegiance to Pakistan despite initial opposition to the partition.

Here "he had declared his allegiance to Pakistan" is the main independent clause, relying on a dependent clause before it (and a relative clause after it). Putting "however" in here instead of "although" would be a bit tricky, and would probably require a quite different structure with "however" acting in a different functionality.